# Почему вылезло 409, если у меня даже вебхуков в коде нет?

Tags: python, файлы, telegram-bot

У меня возникла новая проблема, я написал часть кода под отправку фотографий телеграм-боту, но при запуске кода возникает ошибка, связанная с getUpdates. Вебхуков нет, я в этом убедился. Может быть, это связано с отстуствием этого getUpdates? В каком месте это исправить?

Код:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = 'photo')
def give_photo(photo):
    gp = photo.photo()
    gp.getFile(photo.from_user.id, 'file_id')
    bot.send_photo(photo.chat.id, gp)
```

UPD: этот фрагмент связан с отправкой фотографий.

Comment: это весь код бота?

Comment: это второй хэндлер, первый связан с командой старт, он работает хорошо

Comment: @5c0rp повторяю, это фрагмент, отвечающий за фотографии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg.photo[-1]` - файл с максимальным размером

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def give_photo(msg):
    file = bot.get_file(msg.photo[-1].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file.file_path)
    bot.send_photo(msg.chat.id, downloaded_file)
```

Comment: Тут надо фреймворками пользоваться? И что значит, максимальный размер?

Comment: @parrothi а вы для интереса принтаните msg

Comment: @parrothi про фреймворки вопрос вообще не понял) а в вашем примере разве не фреймворк?))

Comment: @parrothi если мой ответ вам помог то вы можете отметить его как правильный